# Ruby update_all with CASE and WHEN

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-update

Is it possible to use ActiveRecord's update_all function to create a MySQL query like:

```
UPDATE `key_value_store`
SET `key` =
CASE `key`
  WHEN 'xxxxxxx' THEN 'yyyyyyyy'
  WHEN 'zzzzzzz' THEN 'wwwwwwww'
  ...
END
WHERE `key` IN ('some key', 'some other key', ...)
LIMIT 1000
```

What I have now is

```
keys = ['some key', 'some other key', ...]
Keyvaluemodel.where(:key => keys).limit(1000).update_all()
```

So the question is really, what code goes in the update_all brackets so this update works the way I want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible unless you write some raw SQL or a custom query. But considering that you only have two cases, it's easy enough to write two queries.

If [you look at the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) you will see that the only parameter `update_all` accepts is the `SET` part of the SQL query.

> updates - A string, array, or hash representing the SET part of an SQL statement.

So either write a custom query, or split the update into several queries, one for each `CASE`.

```
Model.where(key: key_1).limit(1000).update_all(key: new_key)
Model.where(key: key_2).limit(1000).update_all(key: new_key)
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Too bad this can't be done in one simple statement.

Answer (score 0):

use key-value pair in the parameter like:

`Keyvaluemodel.where(:key => keys).limit(1000).update_all(:key=>'new key')`